# Debugging Blazor Cannot See MyApp.dll in Chrome Debugger and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, google-chrome, webassembly, blazor, blazor-client-side

I am trying to debug a new Blazor Clientside application.

I have based my code on this repo here;

[Authentication With client-side Blazor](https://github.com/chrissainty/AuthenticationWithClientSideBlazor)

I have also referred to the offical documentation here;

[Debug ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

I run the code through ISS Express and in Debug on Visual Studio 2019 preview (I believe this should launch (is this correct??);

```
dotnet run --configuration Debug
```

It launches in Chrome (Version 76.0.3809.100) and I then  `ctrl` & `shift` & `d` which initially opens up the following screen;

[image: Blazor Chrome Dbug Screen 1]

As you can see in the sources this shows a 'file' node tree which allows me to drill down the .razor files. To point out the breakpoints are not being hit at this point.

If I then refresh, navigate to another page, complete an action, etc, then the debug screen reloads with the following;

[image: blazor chrome debug screen refreshed]

At this point I have no 'MyApp.dll'  and I can't debug any of the Blazor code or set any breakpoints? Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here please?